# Error: Column count doesn't match value count

Tags: php, mysql

kindly check this is there any error

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO registration( `date`, `ref`, `name`, `fname`, 
`cell`, `district`, `address`, `gender`, `age`, `face`, `color`, `height`,
 `weight`, `shape`, `disease`, `nationality`, `mother_tongue`, `sect`, 
`cast`, `educational_institution`, `university`, `hobbies`, `skills`, 
`prayer`, `religious_belonging`, `cover_face`, `beard`, `monthly_income`, 
`job_detail`, `house`, `property`, `alive`, `parents_homeland`, 
`father_occupation`, `mother_occupation`, `family_edu`, `birth_no`, 
`brothers`, `sisters`, `married_brothers`, `married_sisters`, 
`second_mrg`, `permission`, `children`, `children_live`, `required_age`, 
`boy_shape`, `boy_color`, `height_boy`, `boy_body`, `mother_lang`, 
`boy_sect`, `boy_cast`, `status`, `college`, `religious`, `balance`, 
`income`, `parents`, `belong_city`, `education`, `family_size`, `system`, 
`requirements`) 

    VALUES ( '$date', '$ref', '$name', '$fname', '$cell', '$district',
'$address', '$gender', '$age', '$face', '$color', '$height', '$weight', 
'$shape', '$disease', '$nationality', '$sect', '$cast', 
'$educational_institution', '$university', '$hobbies', '$skills', 
'$prayer', '$religious_belonging' , '$cover_face', '$beard', 
'$monthly_income', '$job_detail', '$house', '$property', '$alive', 
'$parents_homeland', '$father_occupation', '$mother_occupation', 
'$family_edu', '$birth_no', '$brothers', '$sisters', '$married_brothers', 
'$married_sisters', '$second_mrg', '$permission', '$children', 
'$children_live', '$required_age', '$boy_shape', '$boy_color', 
'$height_boy', '$boy_body', '$mother_lang', '$boy_sect', '$boy_cast', 
'$status', '$college', '$religious', '$balance', '$income', '$parents',
'$belong_city', '$education', '$family_size', '$system', 
'$requirements')";
```

Comment: which type of error are you facing

Comment: Bilal Ahmed #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: if that is the error then count the number of columns and count the number of variables

Comment: that's mean your column and it's value is not match. your column is 64 and your value is 63

Comment: you missed `mother_tongue` field value in variables

Comment: thanku @ravisachaniya

Comment: Please look into prepared statements and bind variables as you will probably find this will break very easily at the moment.  Also open to SQL Injection hacks etc.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments: "that's mean your column and it's value is not match. your column is 64 and your value is 63".

so, `mother_tongue` column value is missing. add `mother_tongue` value like this `$mother_tongue`

Comment: you should accept the correct answer. in future your question is very helpful and valuable for others users

Answer (score 0):

Try to use (" ") in value variable
i.e - "'.$date.'".

Answer (score 0):

To be extremely correct:

1. INSERT INTO registration(

**INSERT INTO registration (**

2. You might try notepad++ or TextWrangler to find and replace all [backtick's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtACu.png) with **'**.

3. Since you have under INSERT INTO `mother_tongue`,

You're missing it from VALUES **'$mother_tongue',**

4. Replace '$religious_belonging' , '$cover_face',

with **'$religious_belonging', '$cover_face',**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code , **mother_tongue** column value is missing :

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO registration( `date`, `ref`, `name`, `fname`, 
`cell`, `district`, `address`, `gender`, `age`, `face`, `color`, `height`,
 `weight`, `shape`, `disease`, `nationality`, `mother_tongue`, `sect`, 
`cast`, `educational_institution`, `university`, `hobbies`, `skills`, 
`prayer`, `religious_belonging`, `cover_face`, `beard`, `monthly_income`, 
`job_detail`, `house`, `property`, `alive`, `parents_homeland`, 
`father_occupation`, `mother_occupation`, `family_edu`, `birth_no`, 
`brothers`, `sisters`, `married_brothers`, `married_sisters`, 
`second_mrg`, `permission`, `children`, `children_live`, `required_age`, 
`boy_shape`, `boy_color`, `height_boy`, `boy_body`, `mother_lang`, 
`boy_sect`, `boy_cast`, `status`, `college`, `religious`, `balance`, 
`income`, `parents`, `belong_city`, `education`, `family_size`, `system`, 
`requirements`) 

    VALUES ( '$date', '$ref', '$name', '$fname', '$cell', '$district',
'$address', '$gender', '$age', '$face', '$color', '$height', '$weight', 
'$shape', '$disease', '$nationality','$mother_tongue', '$sect', '$cast', 
'$educational_institution', '$university', '$hobbies', '$skills', 
'$prayer', '$religious_belonging' , '$cover_face', '$beard', 
'$monthly_income', '$job_detail', '$house', '$property', '$alive', 
'$parents_homeland', '$father_occupation', '$mother_occupation', 
'$family_edu', '$birth_no', '$brothers', '$sisters', '$married_brothers', 
'$married_sisters', '$second_mrg', '$permission', '$children', 
'$children_live', '$required_age', '$boy_shape', '$boy_color', 
'$height_boy', '$boy_body', '$mother_lang', '$boy_sect', '$boy_cast', 
'$status', '$college', '$religious', '$balance', '$income', '$parents',
'$belong_city', '$education', '$family_size', '$system', 
'$requirements')";
```